# Check if element at position [x] exists in the list

Tags: c#, list

If I have a list of strings

```
List<String> list = new list<String>();
list.add("str1");
list.add("str2");
list.add("str3");
```

and I want to know if for example index position 2 contains an element, is there a simple way of doing this without counting the length of the list or using a try catch ?

As this will fail, I can get round it with a try catch, but this seems excessive

```
if(list.ElementAt(2) != null)
{
   // logic
}
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

```
if(list.ElementAtOrDefault(2) != null)
{
   // logic
}
```

*ElementAtOrDefault() is part of the `System.Linq` namespace.*

Although you have a List, so you can use `list.Count > 2`.

Comment: Faster to read than the regular .Count check, but please note than "null" items are theorically valid inside of list, so don't rely on this to throw exception if test is not satisfied.

Comment: You can use the [?? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) ie.```list.ElementAtOrDefault(2)??defaultvalue```

Comment: What if list is a `List<string>`, or a `List<int?>`?  What if the Element at index 2 exists, but has the value of `null`?   `null` doesn't mean there is no element 2.

Comment: @Suamere yes, there are a lot of assumptions around my answer. Another issue is what if the list doesn't contain a reference type, then the default won't be null either.

Answer (score 13):

```
if (list.Count > desiredIndex && list[desiredIndex] != null)
{
    // logic
}
```

Comment: even if list.Count > desiredIndex is satisfied, retrieving the element will throw an exception if index < 0

Comment: well, thats nitpicking. desiredIndex will probably be positive number. If that is not reliable claim, just add desiredIndex > -1..

Comment: @SubjectX - Not nitpicking. It's common to use an index returned by `IndexOf` which can be -1

Answer (score 2):

Inspiring by Yuriy Faktorovich's answer, I have used this. posting here incase it helps anyone in the future.

```
public static bool TryGetElementByIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, out T element)
{
    var e = list.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    if (e != null)
    {
        element = e;
        return true;
    }

    element = default;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int? here = (list.ElementAtOrDefault(2) != 0 ? list[2]:(int?) null);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Also, this question is 7 years old, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue the OP is trying to get at is that `Count()` will have to use the enumerator to `MoveNext()` through the whole `IEnumerator` collection.  The benefit of IEnumerable is that we should be able to stop enumerating when we reach some predicate of known information.

The problem I pointed out with the other answers is that `null` is a valid value in any collection.  So checking if `GetElementAt...()` is `null` isn't reliable.

I have a different implementation and requirement, but I changed it to add an answer for this specific question:

```
public bool TryElementAtOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int index, out T value)
{
    value = default;
    if (index < 0 || source == null || source.Any() == false) return false;

    if (source is IList<T> list && index < list.Count)
    {
        value = list[index];
        return true;
    }

    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                value = e.Current;
                return true;
            }
            index--;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```